# How to modify a member item in a ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm binding a table to a ObservableCollection,

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> Items { get; protected set; }
```

but the table doesn't seem to update (understandably so) when I change the properties one of the items in the collection. How to notify the ObservableCollection that I have changed one of the items' property?

```
MyObject item = Items.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Entity.ID == x);
item.Description = something; //what should I do so that the view will be updated accordingly?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the item instances in the `ObservableCollection` will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For example, if you have an `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`, then `MyObject` will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

Comment: it does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Are you sure that ObservableCollection listens to its member's PropertyChanged?

Comment: @Louis Rhys: it doesn't, but the control (or rather item template) that you bind to it does

Comment: Yes, could you add the code for MyObject. Also, at what point are you populating the items collection? You aren't invoking PropertyChanged in your Items setter, so if that reference changes after construction, then the UI won't be notified.

Comment: the Items notification works fine. The UI is responding to my adding or removing items from there. Only update doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you're invoking the PropertyChanged event in your Description setter on MyObject?

Comment: So the initial Description value is displayed correctly? So you know it's not a binding error in your XAML? Is the binding mode correctly set? Are you able to include the full view model/view code, or better yet an attached solution?